# Example of using Websocket in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, websocket

I am trying to build a sample app that uses web sockets in .Net 4.5. based on the example in here: http://blog.davidpadbury.com/2011/01/13/wcf-websockets-first-glance/

I have VS11 developer preview installed on Windows 7.

I could not figure out which namespace `WebSocketsService` belongs to. 
It would be of great help if anyone can point me to a resource that has complete details to get websockets working in .net.

Thanks.
MK

Comment: Also have a look at: * [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) - there is a client library in a separately linked project
* [XSockets](http://xsockets.net)

Comment: Update: I could not make .net 4.5 web sockets work on windows 7. After some research I came to know that they are not supported on windows7. Looks like the implementation is depends on a change to http.sys, a windows component and only windows 8 has it. For more details 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1732788.aspx/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you [download and install the WCF WebSockets Prototype](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/media/51612/wcfwebsockets.msi) from [HTML5 Labs](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info)?

The namespace is `Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets` in the assembly `Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets.dll`. Once you install the prototype library you should be able to find the assembly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I didn't install WebSockets Prototype. I will try this now.

Comment: I am able to reference WebSockets now. Can you tell me where is WebSocketsHost? Can you refer a detailed example please?

Comment: My mistake. Its in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I spent all day looking for examples that actually worked. So, I decided to put a complete example of web sockets hosted from MVC4 in [**this blog post**](http://kasey-jo.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-net-45-websockets-working.html). It uses the easiest possible way, using the Microsoft.WebSockets NuGet package. It still requires Windows 8 as far as I know. :( Hopefully there will be a patch to make Windows 7 a suitable host.